# Layer download for offline use in Here Maps SDK for Android

Tags: android, here-api

I have uploaded a CLE2 layer to (HERE Platform for Business Admin -[HERE Platform for Business Admin](https://enterprise.cit.here.com/)) , I want to download it in my Android Application for offline use and I am using this code to download the layer:

```
CLE2DataManager.getInstance().newDownloadLayerTask("MYLAYER").start(new CLE2Task.Callback<CLE2OperationResult>() {
@Override
public void onTaskFinished(CLE2OperationResult result, CLE2Error error) {
  if (error.getErrorCode() == CLE2ErrorCode.NONE) {
    // download succeeded
  } else {
    // handle download error
  }
}});
```

I replaced `MYLAYER` with the layer id after uploading it then I got layer does not exist error that looks like as below in debugging

[image: layer does not exist error while debugging]

How can I fix this error? Am I missing something? thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be uploading the layer to the Test Environment (https://enterprise.cit.here.com/) while the SDK tries to download the layer from the Production environment (https://enterprise.here.com/). Try uploading your layer to the Production environment (https://enterprise.here.com/) and then try downloading it via the SDK.

Answer (score 1):

Please check APP_ID and APP_CODE is same you are using between Android and HERE Platform.
And the layer id is case sensitive.

Comment: thanks, I checked all these things also but I got the same error